# Google sheets API fetch the value of Merged cells

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-developers-console

I am using Google Sheets API to display the data from my Google Spreadsheet in my javascript application. Have developed by refering this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). I could able to read the values from my spreadsheet but for some of the columns the cells are merged as below.

[image]

I am getting the Json  response as

```
[
[
  "Name",
  "Age"
 ],
[
  "John",
  "25"
 ],
[
  "Doe"
 
 ],
]
```

My expected output should be

```
   [
[
  "Name",
  "Age"
 ],
[
  "John",
  "25"
 ],
[
  "Doe",
   "25"
 
 ],
]
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the value, you have to test if the cell is part of a merged area.

```
var value = (cell.isPartOfMerge() ? cell.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1,1) : cell).getValue();
```

Comment: Hi where to use this in code ? please help with js documentation sample . https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Comment: share your javascript application (simplified), it could be easier ...

Comment: It is exactly same index.html file given in docs. Only changes are my api credentials.

Comment: I think that you have also change row[4] to row[2], however, try my other answer or post your own script

Answer (score 0):

Modify the script as following

```
    appendPre('Name, Major:');
    var lastData=''
    for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
      var row = range.values[i];
      if (row[4]!=''){lastData=row[4]}
      // Print columns A and lastData, which correspond to indices 0 and the last known value in column E that contains merged cells.
      appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + lastData);
    }
```

so that you will recall the last value if the cell is empty